# Customer session issue for login users in magento1.9.4.4

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, session, customer-session, customer-login

I have problems with front end customer login, I have  checked it with same system and login with two different different customer detail on to the different-2 browsers.

On chrome  I have login with user X details and on Firefox I have login with Y user details.

But on chrome browser  it is showing Y user is login on  some of the pages and some of pages it is showing  loge-din X user.

same for firebox  login with Y but some of pages user showing X and some of page it is showing Y user in magneto 1.9.4.4.

How to fix please give me solutions.

Comment: Weird behavior... Do you test your site on localhost?

Comment: do you use some kind of full page cache, maybe its a misconfiguration there ?

Comment: Thanks @Ekk4rd 
We are using Potato Full Page Cache for magento 1.9 for  our website and its live website. we have configured cache  as per Potato screenshot standard.
but still getting customer session issue.

Comment: as i have checked in header.phtml file and it is showing  incorrect user name for most of pages. i have checked with 
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName(); but it is not working.

Comment: yes @Ekk4rd we are using "Potato_FullPageCache" cache  extension.
cache type is "po_fpc".
as i have checked po_fpc cache is enabled from cache managment then customer session issue come.
but when we disabled cache po_fpc from cache managment.then it is showing right customer name on top.  but it is not showing correct login customer when  "po_fpc" is enabled from cache managemnet.
how to fix or how to disable "po_fpc" cache from cache managemt for login users on top for every page on header section...

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you for your response in the comments, thats pretty much what i would have expected. I don't know exactly how the integration of the Potato_FullPageCache works, but i'm a bit experienced with the Magento2 built-in FPC and the varnish integration in Magento1 and 2.

A good way would be if potato Full page cache offers something similar to ESI blocks of Varnish (Esi blocks for varnish: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.4/users-guide/esi.html)

---

If this isn't an option you have several other possibilities without disabling the full page cache completly, or getting rid of personalized information on cached pages:

1. Requesting the customer name information asyncronously after the page is loaded
2. Adding the current customer ID, logged In state etc. to the cache identifiers of the pages.
   This is something which is done f.e. by the Magento2 Built-In FPC. There a cookie is generated with the current customer_group. This information is then also added to the FPC page identifiers. This results in, that each customer-group has its own cache-entries for each page. You could also do something like this, but for the customers instead of the customer-groups

Comment: thanks  for your quick reply  over my message.
I'm new  in magento, can you please let us know how to disable or cache false for header section for customer session.
is there any way or custom code  for header section with  customer session i want disabled   Potato_FullPageCach through custom code.
how to do can you please let us know so that we can fix by  custom code.

Comment: well a FullPageCache, like the name says, caches the *full* page... there is no disabling the page cache just for the header, except the options i named above using something like esi blocks, or loading the information asynchronously.  
Trying to disable the Cache for logged in customers is closely the same like the option i referred to with (2.). But to know how to accomplish this i would need to know how exactly the Potato_FullPageCache module works, which i don't.

Comment: well a FullPageCache, like the name says, caches the *full* page... there is no disabling the page cache just for the header, except the options i named above using something like esi blocks, or loading the information asynchronously.  
Trying to disable the Cache for logged in customers is closely the same like the option i referred to with (2.). But to know how to accomplish this i would need to know how exactly the Potato_FullPageCache module works, which i don't.

Comment: can you please share with us how to use "esi blocks" or custom code for  fix problmes for   logged in customers because i am new in magento iwant fix problmes for magento 1.9.4.4

Comment: i found this one: https://potatocommerce.com/fpc-exclude, please try to follow this guide to exclude your header (or a more specific block containing this information) from the cache.